# Unable to connect the Sql server 2016 present on another server with the Sql server 2008 management studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008, sql-server-2016, windows-server-2016

### Unable to connect the Sql server 2016 present on another server with the Sql server 2008 management studio.

- We have one remote database which is present in the sql server 2016
  which is present on Server X (We do not know the windows server
  version).
- We have asp.net website which is present on Server Y (windows server
  2008).
- But the site is unable to connect the sql server 2016 (Server X).
- We tried to connect the sql server 2016 from the sql server 2008
  management studio present on Server Y using IP address and port
  number with respective credentials, it still unable to connect.
- But when we try to connect sql server 2016 (Server X) from another
  server (Server Z), which is having windows server 2016 and sql server
  2016 installed, we are able to connect sql server 2016 (Server X)
  successfully using IP address and port number with respective
  credentials of sql server 2016 management studio.

**Does anybody knows what is the problem ? or is there some congfiguration  need to do ?**

Comment: I'm pretty confident in saying the SSMS 2008 is not compatible with SQL Server 2016. SQL Server 2016 is only supported by SSMS 2016 onwards. Use a supported version of SSMS to connect to the server.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved by changing outgoing firewall setting for that site on server (Server Y), we have changed it to "Any", now we are able to establish the connection.